# Blank lines when reading data from Arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I followed the guide to interface the arduino in C++ via serial [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows/).
I included the files since I think mine have changed a bit to make it work...
The problem is exhibited in the picture:

[image]

when I'm expecting:

```
on
off
on
off
.
.
.
```

But instead skips a line. It doesn't appear to skip writing (no missing on or off - also either line write after 1 sec as expected). It seems to simply add another line!
I'm trying to troubleshoot the problem of having a lot of data (new line every 5ms) coming out from an accelerometer and having this new line spacing which I have no idea why it happens. I wonder if it's due to the line buffer? Any help is welcomed!

**SerialPort.h**

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#define ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME 2000
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 255

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class SerialPort
{
private:
    HANDLE handler;
    bool connected;
    COMSTAT status;
    DWORD errors;
public:
    SerialPort(const char* portName);
    ~SerialPort();

    int readSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool writeSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size);
    bool isConnected();
};

#endif // SERIALPORT_H
```

**SerialPort.cpp**

```
#include "SerialPort.h"

SerialPort::SerialPort(const char* portName)
{
    this->connected = false;

    this->handler = CreateFileA(static_cast<LPCSTR>(portName),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);
    if (this->handler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
            printf("ERROR: Handle was not attached. Reason: %s not available\n", portName);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR!!!");
        }
    }
    else {
        DCB dcbSerialParameters = { 0 };

        if (!GetCommState(this->handler, &dcbSerialParameters)) {
            printf("failed to get current serial parameters");
        }
        else {
            dcbSerialParameters.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
            dcbSerialParameters.ByteSize = 8;
            dcbSerialParameters.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
            dcbSerialParameters.Parity = NOPARITY;
            dcbSerialParameters.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

            if (!SetCommState(handler, &dcbSerialParameters))
            {
                printf("ALERT: could not set Serial port parameters\n");
            }
            else {
                this->connected = true;
                PurgeComm(this->handler, PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
                Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);
            }
        }
    }
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    if (this->connected) {
        this->connected = false;
        CloseHandle(this->handler);
    }
}

int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesRead;
    unsigned int toRead = 0;

    ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0) {
        if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size) {
            toRead = buf_size;
        }
        else toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
    }

    if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL)) return bytesRead;

    return 0;
}

bool SerialPort::writeSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    if (!WriteFile(this->handler, (void*)buffer, buf_size, &bytesSend, 0)) {
        ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

bool SerialPort::isConnected()
{
    return this->connected;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SerialPort.h"

#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 255

const char* portName = "\\\\.\\COM3";
SerialPort* arduino;

char receivedString[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];

char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];

int main(void){
    arduino = new SerialPort(portName);
    while (arduino->isConnected()) {
        int hasRead = arduino->readSerialPort(receivedString, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
        if (hasRead) std::cout << receivedString;
        //else std::cerr << "Error occured reading data" << "\n";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Arduino**

```
#define BAUD 115200
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("on");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("off");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to replace all images with pasted text.

Answer (score 1):

You should null-terminate your string/buffer - like this:

```
int main(void){
    arduino = new SerialPort(portName);
    while (arduino->isConnected()) {
        int hasRead = arduino->readSerialPort(receivedString, MAX_DATA_LENGTH - 1);

        receivedString[hasRead] = 0;

        if (hasRead) std::cout << receivedString;
        //else std::cerr << "Error occured reading data" << "\n";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Also note the `MAX_DATA_LENGTH - 1` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Actually checked this after figuring that it made no sense to not flush the data after each iteration. I found this somewhere: memset(receivedString, 0, sizeof(receivedString)) but I like yours better (sounds equivalent to me on paper). Also, well noted for the -1!!!

Comment: FYI memset(receivedString, 0, sizeof(receivedString)) is the correct way to clear the string. My issue arises due to serial communication being slow. Sometimes the buffer didn't write everything and it finishes the next loop (arduino side). This is why I ended with lack of \n (and also \0 - so your suggestion is just but not complete!)